# construct function in $C_{c}^{\infty}$

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

Construct a sequence of functions $\phi_n \in C_{c}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$, $0 \le \phi_{n}(x) \le 1$ $\forall$ $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that

$\phi_n(x)=1$ if $x \in (a,b) $ and $\phi_n(x)=0$ if $x<a-\frac{1}{n}$ or $x>b+\frac{1}{n}$

prove that: $\phi_n \rightarrow \chi_{(a,b)}$ in $L^{p}$

i could do if $\phi_n \in C_{c}^{k}$, but with this problem I have trouble.
i tried to construct $\phi_n$ many times but all of them are fail

Comment: I'm surprised this isn't already covered in your textbook. For example this is covered in great detail in Strichartz *The Way of Analysis*, sections 8.1.2 and 8.1.3.

Comment: Let $\psi(x) = e^{-1/x}$ for $x > 0$ and $\psi(x) = 0$ for $x \leq 0$ and compose it with some suitable function $h$ to make a function $\psi \circ h$ with compact support. "Normalize" $\psi \circ h$ to have $\int \cdot \, dx = 1$ and support inside $(-\frac1n, +\frac1n)$. Then take the convolution of this with $\chi_{[a, b]}$ (which equals $1$ on $[a,b]$ and $0$ otherwise).

Answer (score 0):

For each $n\in \mathbb N$ we can do the following. There exists a smooth $f$ with support in $[a-1/n,a]$ with $f>0$ on $(a-1/n,a)$ such that $\int_{a-1/n}^a f = 1.$ And there exists a a smooth $g$ with support in $[b,b+1/n]$ with $g<0$ on $(b,b+1/n)$ such that $\int_{b}^{b+1/n} g = -1.$

Define

$$\phi_n(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x (f(t) + g(t)\,dt.$$

Then $\phi_n$ is smooth, with support in $[a-1/n,b+1/n],$ such that $0<F<1$ on $(a-1/n,a),$ $F=1$ on $[a,b],$ and $0<F<1$ on $(b,b+1/n).$ The functions $\phi_n$ do what you want.

Comment: Well the support of $F^n$ doesn't $\to [a,b]$

Comment: @reuns You're right, I missed that. I'll fix it. Thanks.